# Logistic Regression and modelling probabiliy $\pi$

Tags: statistics, transformation

This is a General Linear Models topic but I believe it's just basic failure to remember some more basic math rules that's making it difficult for me.

---

If the link function is

$$g(\pi) = \log(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}) = x^T\beta$$

show that this is equivalent to modeling the probability $\pi$ as,

$$\pi = \frac{e^{x^T}\beta}{1+e^{x^T}\beta}$$

Again I think this is a simply inverse. But I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it is just the inverse

$$
\ln\frac{\pi}{1 - \pi} = x^T\beta  ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \frac{\pi}{1 - \pi} = e^{x^T\beta} ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \pi = (1 - \pi)e^{x^T\beta} = e^{x^T\beta} - \pi e^{x^T\beta}
$$

Now rearrange a bit things

$$
\pi (1  + e^{x^T\beta}) = e^{x^T\beta}
$$

and from here

$$
\pi = \frac{e^{x^T\beta}}{1 + e^{x^T\beta}}
$$

Comment: Thank you kindly! I'm not sure why I kept stopping myself at the part where we multiply the exponential by $(1-\pi)$. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @Nicklovn Happy to help